# MPI messages garbled on certain processors

Tags: c++, mpi

Part of my code partitions a finite element mesh that originally exists entirely on process 0 and sends pieces of it to the other processors. This involves sending lists of node ids among other data to the other processors. My code looks somewhat like this:

```
std::vector<std::vector<unsigned int> > id_send_lists(nproc);
// Fill in the id lists with correct ids here...

if (rank==0){
    MPI_Request reqs[nproc-1];
    for (int p=1; p<nproc; ++p){
        MPI_Isend(node_id_lists[p].data(), node_id_lists[p].size(), MPI_UNSIGNED, p, 0, _communicator, &reqs[p-1]);
    }
    MPI_Waitall(nproc-1, reqs.data(), MPI_STATUSES_IGNORE);
}
else{
    MPI_Status status;
    int count;
    std::vector<unsigned int> id_recv_vec;
    MPI_Probe(0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
    MPI_GetCount(&status, MPU_UNSIGNED, &count);
    id_recv_vec.resize(count);
    MPI_Recv(id_recv_vec.data(), count, MPI_UNSIGNED, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
    // Parse the id vector and create nodes here...
}
```

However, for some reason my messages are sometimes getting garbled along the way, depending on which recieving processor I'm looking at and how many processors I'm running on. For example, my code seems to work perfectly fine when running on 1 through 5 processors but when I run on 6 processors the messages getting sent to processor 3 get garbled somewhere along the way and only random integers are recieved. The recieved messages on processors, 1, 2, 4, and 5 are fine however. Additionally, I checked the ids before they were sent on processor 0 and they appeared to be fine there.

Oddly enough it runs fine again on 7 processors, and then on 8 or more processors there's always at least one processor that recieves garbled messages.

Comment: Your for loop is over `p`, but you use `i` within the loop. Is that just a posting error?

Comment: Oh whoops, thanks. Yes, that was just a posting error. Fixed.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Your code looks fine,  the error may be elsewhere or in the configuration. Can you please provide a [mcve] for this issue?